# Delete entire row using Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX

Tags: excel, perl, xlsx

I'm new to spreadsheet parsers in general, and can't find much info on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Spreadsheet-ParseXLSX-0.17/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseXLSX.pm) other than a basic introduction of the main features.

I'm trying to read in a .xlsx file and delete an entire row if `column 2` exists in a hash that I'm filtering against.

Then I want to print out the an edited file, also in .xlxs

This is what I can find from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~dougw/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm) for `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;


my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new;
my $workbook = $parser->parse("file.xlsx");


for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) { 
    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();
    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {

        # Here I want to delete an entire row if a column 2 of that row matches a value

        # sudo code:
        # delete 'row' if 'row column 2' exists $hash{$key}

        # And then print out the edited .xlsx file

        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Is `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` the right module to use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX` is just for reading spreadsheets. It doesn't have facilities for updating and saving data from Perl to an Excel spreadsheet.

Then there are modules like [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel) and [`Excel::Writer::XLSX`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX) that can write spreadsheets but can't read them.

But put them together in the same script? Stand back and watch the magic happen.